# Java Properties vs Android SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, properties, sharedpreferences

The goal seems to be the same: to store key-value pairs. Is there a difference in concept between one and the other?

Comment: There is no real difference in the concept, but there certainly is a big difference in implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell, `Properties` is a `HashTable` that lets you store key-value pairs on memory with the option of persisting them in XML(and other formats). I do not know where this XML would be stored in Android; you probably need to define a location.

`SharedPreferences` on the other hand, are guaranteed to be stored on disk space that only your app can access.

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref):

> The SharedPreferences class provides a general framework that allows
>   you to save and retrieve persistent key-value pairs of primitive data
>   types. You can use SharedPreferences to save any primitive data:
>   booleans, floats, ints, longs, and strings. This data will persist
>   across user sessions (even if your application is killed).

If you need your key-value pairs to be persisted and you don't want to worry about implementations, I would prefer SharedPreferences.

In the case of a properties file you will new to write code to store the modified properties.